# Jquery button click() function is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create dynamic form where user can add dynamic text-fields based on their requirement. Here is my jquery code ..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#add").click(function() {
        var intId = $("#buildyourform div").length +1;
        var fieldWrapper = $("<div class=\"fieldwrapper\" name=\"field" + intId + "\" id=\"field" + intId + "\"/>");
        var fName = $("<input type=\"text\" name=\"name\" class=\"fieldname\" id=\"tb"+ intId +"_1\"/>");
        var lname = $("<input type=\"text\" name=\"email\" class=\"lastname\" id=\"tb"+ intId +"_2\"/>");
        var removeButton = $("<input type=\"button\" class=\"remove\" value=\"-\" />");

        var addButton = $("<input type=\"button\" class=\"add\" id=\"add\" value=\"+\" />")
        removeButton.click(function() {
            $(this).parent().remove();
        });
        fieldWrapper.append(fName);
        fieldWrapper.append(lname);
        fieldWrapper.append(removeButton);
        fieldWrapper.append(addButton);
        $(this).remove();
        $("#buildyourform").append(fieldWrapper);

    });

});
```

and Html code is ...

```
<fieldset id="buildyourform">
    <legend>Build your own form!</legend>
    <div class="fieldwrapper" name="field1" id="field1" />
       <input type="text" name="name" class="fieldname" id="tb1_1" />
       <input type="text" name="email" class="lastname" id="tb1_2" />
       <input type="button" value="+" class="add" id="add" />
    </div>
</fieldset> 
<input type="submit" value="send" id="asdasd" name="submit" />
```

Check my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4QtB4/) also.

Whats wrong with me is when user click on "+" button first time then click function working and it adds two text-fields into my fieldset. But after that when i click on "+" button, its not triggering click function. May be id conflict. Please help.

Comment: `May be id conflict.` - Have you tried resolving the conflict yourself?

Comment: You're re-using the id "add" on your new buttons. Values for "id" attributes can only be used once on a page. *edit* oh wait, you remove the original button. Well that's the problem then :)

Comment: I had this same problem but my element was not dynamically generated, it was a plain ol' element on the page. I believe it was due to interference from Knockout.js.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You need to use the event delegation syntax of `.on()` here. Change:

```
$("#add").click(function() {
```

to

```
$("#buildyourform").on('click', '#add', function () {
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/4QtB4/1/)**

Comment: I have one more problem, when i click on "+" button, its added two text-fields. Suppose I added 4 to 5 textfields and now i am trying to remove each fields using "-" button. When I reached to my second div element and click on "-" then it removes "+" button also from my first div element. Is there any way to add event on first "-" button so that after click on "-" it should add back "+" button into my first div element??

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to just move the + button so that it stayed in the same place and you weren't constantly moving it?

Comment: @j08691 i don't want this

Comment: Well then if I understand you correctly, you'd need to check when the last row was deleted, and then just add a new add button to what becomes the new last row.

Comment: yes that exactly i want @j08691

Comment: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/4QtB4/3/?

Comment: Ya thanks, thats I want, but its not working at first level. Means when i click on + and then - its not adding + button to my first div element.

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/4QtB4/4/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35296/discussion-between-shreshtt-bhatt-and-j08691)

Comment: -1 you need to explain the difference between the two click syntax. Why do you use the .on instead of .click? I know why, but this is half an answer.

Comment: @michaelhanon It says right there in the answer, "event delegation syntax". If you, or someone else, is unfamiliar with that term, they can easily Google it or look at the duplicate of this question.

Comment: The user already googled, and found this on Stack. We can agree to disagree, but you and I both know, on stack, you're supposed to explain the answer.

Comment: This helped me. Take my upvote

Answer (score 19):

You need to use a delegated event handler as the `#add` elements dynamically appended won't have the click event bound to them. Try this:

```js
$("#buildyourform").on('click', "#add", function() {
    // your code...
});
```

Also, you can make your HTML strings easier to read by mixing line quotes:

```js
var fieldWrapper = $('<div class="fieldwrapper" name="field' + intId + '" id="field' + intId + '"/>');
```

Or using string interpolation (ES6 feature, so this won't work in IE):

```js
var fieldWrapper = $(`<div class="fieldwrapper" name="field${intId}" id="field${intId}"/>`);
```

Or even supplying the attributes as an object:

```js
var fieldWrapper = $('<div></div>', { 
  class: 'fieldwrapper',
  name: 'field' + intId,
  id: 'field' + intId
});
```

Answer (score 3):

After making the `id` unique across the `document` ,You have to use [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$("#container").on("click", "buttonid", function () {
  alert("Hi");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The click event is not bound to your new element, use a `jQuery.on` to handle the click.